# differentiable on open interval zero elsewhere

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

When thinking about another question I came across this and wonder if it's true:

If $F$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$ and continuous at $[a, b]$, then given $g (x) = F^{\prime} (x)$ on $(a, b)$ and $g (a) = g (b)
= 0$, is it true that $\int_a^b g (x) d x = F (b) - F (a)$?

[edit] Am I really just using the definition of indefinite integrals here?

Comment: Why do you need $g(a)=g(b)=0$?

Comment: @KittyL (weird) problem constraints.

Comment: I believe the statement is true without that.

Comment: If $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$, then if you define $g(x)=F'(x)$, it is (in general) **NOT** true that $g(a)=g(b)=0.$

Comment: @5xum g is given, I've phrased that more clearly now.

Comment: @simonzack: You need to assume $F'$ is integrable; this is not automatic from differentiability. (Counterexample: $F(x) = x^{2} \sin(1/x^{2})$ on $(0, 1]$, $F(0) = 0$; $F'$ exists throughout $[0, 1]$ but is unbounded.) It would also help clarify if you'd specify whether you're talking about Riemann integrals, and whether or not you're willing to view $\int_{a}^{b} g$ as an _improper_ integral. :)

Comment: @user86418 Is your $F$ continuous on $[0, 1]$ though? My question is related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211490/proving-a-theorem-for-densities-of-functions-of-random-variables), where the integral is for the definition of absolutely continuous random variables, the book I'm reading defines it using a Riemann integral, I think improper integrals are allowed there right?

Comment: @simonzack: Yes, that $F$ is actually differentiable (hence continuous) on $[0, 1]$. However, $F$ is _not_ continuously differentiable (a condition mentioned in your other post). If you assume $F$ is _continuously_ differentiable, then the answer to your question is "yes by the FTC, because changing the value of an integrable function at finitely many points does not change the value of the integral".

Comment: @user86418 Thanks. What if I don't have continuous differentiability but allow improper integrals, is this still correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $F:[a, b] \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous, differentiable in $(a, b)$, and that $g(x) = F'(x)$ if $a < x < b$, and $g(a) = g(b) = 0$. Fix a point $x_{0}$ in $(a, b)$ arbitrarily. By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} g(z)\, dz
  = \int_{x_{0}}^{x} F'(z)\, dz
  = F(x) - F(x_{0})\quad\text{for all $x$ in $(a, b)$.}
$$
Since $F$ is continuous at $b$,
$$
\int_{x_{0}}^{b} g(z)\, dz
  = \lim_{x \to b^{-}} \int_{x_{0}}^{x} g(z)\, dz
  = \lim_{x \to b^{-}} F(x) - F(x_{0})
  = F(b) - F(x_{0}).
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int_{a}^{x_{0}} g(z)\, dz = F(x_{0}) - F(a).
$$

That is, in the sense of improper integrals,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} g(z)\, dz
  = \lim_{x \to a^{+}} \lim_{y \to b^{-}} \int_{x}^{y} g(z)\, dz
  = F(b) - F(a).
$$